# Working directory of Visual Studio Code tasks

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-tasks

What is the working directory of a Visual Studio Code task?

According to the official documentation, the default should be the workspace directory, i.e., `workspaceFolder`, but running a task which simply executes `echo $PWD`, it shows the parent directory of `workspaceFolder`.

In other words, given `dir1/dir2/.vscode/tasks.json`, the following trivial task prints `dir1` while the `workspaceFolder` refers to `dir2` (the actual workspace directory).

What should I do to run a task from the `workspaceFolder`? Changing the `cwd` option does not help.

`tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Sample",
            "command": "echo PWD=$PWD workspaceFolder=${workspaceFolder}",
            "options": {
              "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Execution output:

```console
> Executing task: echo PWD=$PWD workspaceFolder=/home/ubuntu/dir1/dir2 <

PWD=/home/ubuntu/dir1 workspaceFolder=/home/ubuntu/dir1/dir2
```

As additional and probably relevant note, I am developing remotely using the *Remote - SSH* extension.

Comment: I just tried with remote SSH to a VirtualBox Ubuntu and I get the expected behavior, PWD==Workspacefolder

Comment: This was probably a bug of the version I was using because today, using the latest version of VSCode and its extensions, the same task configuration works as expected.

Comment: Long after your comment, *VSCode* still has the same issue: every time there is a new version, it gets completely broken and needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 19):

```json
{
    "label": "Status",
    "detail": "git status",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "git status",
    "group": "test",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/dir1/dir2/dir3/"
    },
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new",
        "focus": true
    }
}
```

We can use the "options" key to set the working directory the task should execute in.

Comment: As I said in the description, this configuration did not solve the problem. However, after updating VSCode the problem was resolved without change my `tasks.json` file.

Comment: This helped me find what I was looking for, which is setting `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"` under the `options` key.